# Any workarounds for checkspelling

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to extract all the 5-letter words that are allowed in application.checkspelling function and thought of using 5 nested forloops to check through aaaaa-zzzzz and insert words that are valid into the cells.

however the application.checkspelling function runs very slowly

```
Sub test()
    t = Timer
    counter = 3
    howmanyword = 0

   'cells(1,1) = "a", cells(1,2) = "b", so on and so forth
    For Each cell1 In Cells.Find("a", , , xlWhole).CurrentRegion
        For Each cell2 In Cells.Find("a", , , xlWhole).CurrentRegion
            For Each cell3 In Cells.Find("a", , , xlWhole).CurrentRegion
                For Each cell4 In Cells.Find("a", , , xlWhole).CurrentRegion
                    For Each cell5 In Cells.Find("a", , , xlWhole).CurrentRegion

                           wordsearch = cell1.Value + cell2.Value + cell3.Value + cell4.Value + cell5.Value
                           If Application.CheckSpelling(wordsearch) = True Then
                                Cells(counter, 1).Value = wordsearch
                                counter = counter + 1
                                howmanyword = howmanyword + 1
                                Cells(counter - 1, 1).Select
                            End If
                            
                            If howmanyword = 200 Then GoTo 0
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
    
0:
MsgBox Timer - t '163.377
End Sub
```

the code took almost 3minutes just to obtain 200 valid words.
is there a more efficient approach to doing this? thank you!!

code and explanation are described above, appreciate your help :)

Comment: How about running this in memory, placing the values in a dictionary and then printing the keys? Accessing Excel so many times with `.Find` and `.Value` is bound to make it as slow as molasses . I haven't used `.CheckSpelling()` yet so I don't know if that takes a while but skipping all the rest should surely speed things up.

Comment: ahhs thankyou for suggesting about running in memory instead, unfortunately as FunThomas mentioned .CheckSpelling() is the main problem that's slowing everything down :")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid your attempt is doomed to fail. Why? Because the spell checker is way too slow.

Your code will call the spell checker for 26 to the power of 5 times, that's nearly 12 million times.

You can improve the speed of your code by getting the characters without using Excel, eg like this (note that the spell check part is disabled)

```
Sub test()
    Const MaxWords = 200
    Const TestWithSpellcheck = False
    Const characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    Dim words(1 To MaxWords, 1 To 1) As String, wordIndex As Long
    
    Dim startTime As Double: startTime = Timer
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long, i4 As Long, i5 As Long
    For i1 = 1 To Len(characters)
        For i2 = 1 To Len(characters)
            For i3 = 1 To Len(characters)
                For i4 = 1 To Len(characters)
                    For i5 = 1 To Len(characters)
                        Dim word As String
                        word = Mid(characters, i1, 1) _
                             & Mid(characters, i2, 1) _
                             & Mid(characters, i3, 1) _
                             & Mid(characters, i4, 1) _
                             & Mid(characters, i5, 1)
                             
                        If TestWithSpellcheck Then
                            If Application.CheckSpelling(word) Then
                                wordIndex = wordIndex + 1
                                words(wordIndex, 1) = word
                                If wordIndex >= MaxWords Then GoTo overAndOut
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next i5
                Next i4
            Next i3
        Next i2
    Next i1
                        
overAndOut:
    
    Debug.Print "It took " & Timer - startTime & " s"
    If wordIndex > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(maxWords, 1) = words
    End If
End Sub
```

This runs approx 20s on my computer, with nearly no room for improvement.

Now I enabled the spell checker (`TestWithSpellcheck = True`), but limited the outer 2 loops to `From 1 To 1`. With other words, only 26 to the power of 3 (=17'576) words where checked. This resulted in a runtime of > 3 min. So 99.99% of the runtime is lost using the spell check, and you can't do anything against that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and explaining so clearly using the code! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote yet, will do so once i gather enough :")